# Zend -> Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: zend-framework, open-basedir

I am getting the following warning in my code:

```
      Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect.   File(/usr/share/php/./views/helpers/Doctype.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/virtual/example.com/:/usr/share/pear/) in /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/rockhopper-v2/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 198

or

      Warning: is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect.   File(/usr/share/php//var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/rockhopper-v2/application/modules/default/views/helpers/Layout.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/virtual/example.com/:/usr/share/pear/) in /var/www/virtual/example.com/htdocs/rockhopper-v2/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 198
```

what is the problem and will it cause problems in deployment and production stage of my application?

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This message appears because since Zend FW 1.10.1 the autoloader creates the path to those files differently. You can find some more information here: [Zend FW Bug Report](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9263)

To get rid of this message you can edit the file index.php and change the set_include_path to this:

```
set_include_path(
APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library'.PATH_SEPARATOR.
APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/Zend'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

open_basedir is set php is running in safe mode. It restricts you to the folders specified in the list. This might help: http://blog.php-security.org/archives/72-Open_basedir-confusion.html

And yes, you will need to change it on any server if you want to access files outside the default folder.

Comment: open_basedir is not safe mode directive. at least for >5.2.x