# Zend Framework 1.11.11 Include Path open_basedir issues

Tags: php, zend-framework, relative-path, include-path

I've seen a number of questions on this site regarding this exact issue, but I'm fairly certain that my case is a bit different.  I recently upgraded from ZF 1.9.6 to 1.11.11 and since then things stopped working on my production server.

My localhost is running PHP **5.3.8** while the server is running **5.2.11**.  I am not sure if that has anything to do with it but I figured I would mention it just in case.

When I first upgraded the framework, I was getting a bunch of `open_basedir restriction in effect.` errors.  I resolved that exactly how several others mentioned, by removing the `get_include_path()` from the call to `set_include_path()` in the index.php file.  [As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5696784/486233).

That fixed the open_basedir errors, but now I'm having issues elsewhere.  In several different files for various reasons I am including files via the `include` and `require` statements using *relative* paths.

For example:

```
require_once 'application/models/MyModel.php';
```

But now that suddenly doesn't work anymore!  I've had to suddenly prepend all those paths with a `./` like so:

```
require_once './application/models/MyModel.php';
```

The problem is, there are way too may instances of that to manually go through and find all of them and change it.  Rather, I want to figure out *why* those paths no longer work on the server but continue to work on my localhost.

My inclination is that it has something to do with the fact that I no longer include the `get_include_path()` part in the `set_include_path()` in the index.php file but I am not sure.

Can anyone shed some insight?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) about open_basedir:

> The restriction specified with open_basedir is a directory name since PHP 5.2.16 and 5.3.4. Previous versions used it as a prefix.

The difference between checking it as a prefix and checking it as a directory would definitely cause problems like this.

A solution might have something to do with [this note](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in the PHP documentation:

> Using a . in the include path allows for relative includes as it means the current directory. However, it is more efficient to explicitly use include './file' than having PHP always check the current directory for every include.

So when setting your include path, I think you should modify the example you linked to like this:

```
set_include_path(
    APPLICATION_PATH . './../library' . PATH_SEPARATOR .
    APPLICATION_PATH . './../library/Zend'
);
```

Notice the "." I added before the first forward slash. This should make it relative to the current working directory and stop you from having to make your includes like `./file`.

Also, that says this method is less efficient so you can also consider using a tool such as [TextCrawler](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/textcrawler) to do find & replace on multiple files.

---

Additionally, you can include **'.'** (current directory - or *document root*) in your include path when setting it.  Like so:

```
set_include_path(APPLICATION_PATH . '../library' 
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPLICATION_PATH . '../library/Zend' 
    . PATH_SEPARATOR . '.' // <-- notice this!
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch for your reply, it was very informative!  I'm gonna give that a try and I'll let you know tomorrow what the deal is.

Comment: I solved this with the solution I added to your answer. Your answer was great though either way!  Cheers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for adding that bit to the answer, hopefully it helps someone else down the road!